# Java Thread.sleep() different between servers

Tags: java, centos, sleep

### Setup

I have 2 servers, they are supposed to be basically the same.

i.e. All these values are identical:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)

Linux server1.fake.com 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 15:42:40 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.7) (rhel-1.39.1.9.7.el6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

## alternatives --display java
 link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java - priority 1500
 [...snip...]
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java.
```

global environment variables are also nearly identical.

We have a bit of Java code that calls Thread.sleep(250). It was written in 2008 and still does exactly what we need it to do. It is exactly the same code on both servers, installed in the same location at the same time with the same user and permissions.

### The Issue

Now we want to actually start using it on the second server.

- On server 1 the code correctly pauses for 250ms (...ish)
- On server 2 the code pauses for 3 minutes 38 seconds! (approx 850x longer)

### Investigation

- The code behaves consistently on both servers.
- It is not specific to the delay value i.e. value 1 pauses for 1ms on server 1, 1 second on server 2. Value 100: server1 = 100ms, server 2 ~= 1 minute.
- Neither server is under significant load.
- I have checked for libfaketime (the only thing Google brings up as a likely cause) but it is not installed on either server.

### Help

Does anyone have any suggestions where this massive time delay might be coming from?

Very, very confused!

Comment: Given that Java 7 is not freely supported, nor Java 6, nor Java 5.0 and especially not GCJ which wasn't even a complete version of Java 5.0, can you not use a more recent version of the JVM?

Comment: Are the servers running these tests on a VM ?

Comment: `global environment variables are also nearly identical.` I guess we will have to go deeper into the `nearly` part. I can't see anything else that could be possible cause such results.

Comment: @ Mohammad Ghazanfar: The servers are both HP DL380 G7 with 16 cores with about 100Gb Ram. Running Centos directly on the metal

Comment: @Wookie I am trying to figure something out but I have had no luck till now. Still trying. One other similar [thing is here](http://www.jwrapper.com/blog/worst-bug-ever-java-sleeps-3-orders-of-magnitude-too-long)

Comment: @ Mohammad Ghazanfar: What from the environment variables might have this effect. Nothing in env mentions Java, not even the path. 
@Peter Lawrey: Yes we know, one day we might upgrade everything, but this is way down the very long priority list. Also the code works fine just this delay difference.

Comment: @Wookie It is possible/likely the problem is with your OS as Thread.sleep(n) doesn't do much except call the OS.  You could find that Java 8 does exactly the same thing, but at least you could say this is not a bug in Java which was later fixed.

Comment: @Mohammad: Thanks for the OSX link, sound very similar to what we are experiencing, though I'm not sure how I can apply that fix that in the JVM I have.

Comment: @Peter: We will be moving away from those servers soon-ish so we will probably just hope the error doesn't reproduce itself on the new servers. I dream of being able to update our system but the system is large and overly complex and there are so few of us left to maintain it that its hard to find time to upgrade things that are basically working... which in this case is half true. For now we are just ignoring the problem and relying on the working server. Fortunately its not super critical, nor heavily used so we'll be ok... still frustrating

Comment: @Martin the problem with old versions is that they become increasingly unsupportable, not that means you have more time to support them ;)

Comment: @Martin Did you manage to figure out what was going wrong ?

Comment: @Mohammad : Sorry no. I am tempted to try Peter's option and upgrade our Java version but finding the time is tricky. I will post back if I ever find out what is wrong, but I suspect the servers will be replaced before I do.

Comment: @Martin I'm very curious about what's wrong with it ! I spent a good amount of time trying to figure it out.